# SQL Server - Aggregate previous 5 months sales data to current month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sum, aggregation

I need to aggregate sales of previous five months to current month for each record. In the table below for example,

```
StoreID |Month |Sales

-----------|----------|----------

119119   |201802|50000

119119   |201803|62500

119119  |201804|93750

119119  |201708|45000

119271  |201803|25000

119271  |201804|75000

119271  |201802|50000
```

StoreID 119119's aggregated sales for Month 201804 should be 50000+62500+93750.

Aggregated sales for 119119 for Month 201803 should be 62500+50000 and so on.

I need to do this so that I will be able to plot this aggregated column on a time-series graph.

I cannot use ASC ROWS 5 PRECEEDING here because there may not be sales data for every month and I should not aggregate previous 5 records but it should be strictly based on previous 5 months sales data.

Is it possible to do this without using cursors? Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: storing `Month` in that way looks like an horrible design ... if you can change the db structure change that column in _DATETIME_

Comment: what's month stored as? Int? varchar?

Comment: Month is stored as Int.

Comment: You can do this with a self join with a between for the previous months by each StoreID, then group by StoreID and original Month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self join to get the older values. ie:

```
DECLARE @stores TABLE(StoreID INT, [Month] VARCHAR(6), Sales INT);
INSERT INTO @stores(StoreID, Month, Sales)
VALUES(119119, '201802', 50000),
    (119119, '201803', 62500),
    (119119, '201804', 93750),
    (119119, '201708', 45000),
    (119271, '201803', 25000),
    (119271, '201804', 75000),
    (119271, '201802', 50000);


WITH
    Sales AS (SELECT StoreID, CAST([Month]+'01' AS DATE) AS [Month], Sales FROM @stores)
SELECT s1.StoreID, s1.[Month], SUM(s2.Sales) AS total
FROM Sales s1
     inner JOIN Sales s2 ON s1.StoreID=s2.StoreID
                       AND s1.[Month]>=s2.[Month]
                       AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, s2.[Month], s1.[Month])<5
GROUP BY s1.StoreID, s1.[Month]
ORDER BY s1.StoreID, s1.[Month];
```